# FormatException Error in at cell validating

Tags: c#, winforms, double

When i load the file into the datagrid, i'm getting a error message, `FormatException Error`. 
Here, what i'm trying to do, comparing the two cell vlaues, if the col index 2 value is greater than col index 3, then show a error message.

When iload the file for the first time, i have no issues. I fi load for the `seconfd time, i'm gettign the above error message`.

I tried using `Convert.ToInt32, int`, still i'm getting the same error message. How can i fix this??

```
private void datagridview_CellValidating(object sender, CellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
if (e.ColumnIndex != 0)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex < 8)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value != null)
        {
                //Convert.ToInt32, int////
            if (Double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) <=
                Double.Parse(datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
                e.Cancel = true;
                datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = errorMesssage;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are the values you see when parsing ? Maybe the value being checked is for `Column1` which cannot be parsed (since you have `Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1]` )

Comment: What data type should be in e.Value? What kind of file are you reading in?

Comment: I'm reading a Xml file which has some big integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should revisit your condition here

```
if (Double.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) <=    
    Double.Parse(datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString()))
```

Now what would happen when you are validating for `Column1` the comparison would be with the value available in `Column2` and `Column1` (not as what you mentioned), so if the Value in `Column1` cannot be parsed then it would pop up a format exception since it cannot be parsed.

So maybe you need to specify the columns in your if clause

`if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) // here you allow for Column3, so that e.ColumnIndex - 1 is 2`

Comment: I don't understand why it's happening. If ii load for the second time, i'm gettign the above error message. I tried your code, stil the same problem. Could you please explain to me a bit more.

Comment: @linguini What i meant is if your first column has a value which cannot be parsed something like "Apple", so when you have it parsed it would throw a format exception, so the integer values you have are only in the 2 and 3 column and not in the first, maybe you can put up a sample layout of the values

Comment: So stupid of me. Just chnaged it `if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 && e.ColumnIndex != 2 && e.ColumnIndex != 3)`it works.